# int to hex string

Tags: c#

I need to convert an int to hex string.

When converting `1400 => 578` using `ToString("X")` or `ToString("X2")` but I need it like `0578`.

Can anyone provide me the `IFormatter` to ensure that the string is 4 chars long?

Comment: Look at numerics formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Use `ToString("X4")`.

The 4 means that the string will be 4 digits long.

Reference: [The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString).

Comment: It is not good for negative numbers, use a 'short' type instead of 'int'

Comment: To print an int32 it should just use "X8", not "X4". If you want X4, you should indeed make sure to use an Int16.

Answer (score 21):

Try [C# string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) introduced in C# 6:

```
var id = 100;
var hexid = $"0x{id:X}";
```

hexid value:

```
"0x64"
```

Comment: Great! I will add `$"0x{id:X4}";`

Answer (score 18):

Try the following:

```
ToString("X4")
```

See The [`X` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answer is not good for negative numbers. Use a short type instead of int

```
        short iValue = -1400;
        string sResult = iValue.ToString("X2");
        Console.WriteLine("Value={0} Result={1}", iValue, sResult);
```

Now result is FA88

Answer (score 2):

Convert int to hex string

```
int num = 1366;
string hexNum = num.ToString("X");
```