# Decimal to Hex in middle of hex command

Tags: c#

I am trying to print stored bitmap images in some printers.
The program is a Windows Form.
The command to print the logo (bitmap)-(if there is one stored) is:

```
port.Write("\x1C\x70\x01\x00");
```

('port' being my name for new serial port object).

There can be from 0 to 255 DEC (00 to FF HEX) different locations in the 
printers memory.
I need a for loop or while loop that will increment the above line of code so,

```
port.Write("\x1C\x70\x01\x00"); would become
port.Write("\x1C\x70\x02\x00");
port.Write("\x1C\x70\x03\x00"); up to FF
port.Write("\x1C\x70\xFF\x00");
```

etc etc.

I looked on MSDN & Search Stack Overflow:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx
- [int to hex string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690480/int-to-hex-string)

Comment: Note that `"\x1C\x70\x01\x00"` is not a hex string, it's a regular string made up of regular character literals where you have used a [hexedecimal escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx) to declare the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, as an alternative to Coriths solution.  The `SerialPort` object lets you write a byte array directly, rather than converting your bytes to a string that the `SerialPort` then converts back into bytes again.

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    var bytes = new byte[] { 0x1C, 0x70, i, 0x00 };
    port.Write(bytes, 0, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop should work for you.  You can always use 0x to work in hexadecimal numbers in your loops.

```
for(var c = 0x01; c <= 0xFF; c++)
{
  port.Write($"\x1C\x70\x{c:X2}\x00");
}
```

Comment: `"\x1C\x70\x01\x00"` doesn't equal `"\x1C\x70" + 0x01 + "\x00"`. For example, `"\x41"` is the Unicode character `A` but `0x41` is just the number `65`.

Comment: Quantic, give the edit a try.  I don't have immediate access to a compiler, but I didn't quite see that you were trying to output unicode characters.  This should lead you down the right path but I can still help if you have other questions.

Comment: I'm not the asker, but I'm pretty sure they have a similar issue where even with your fixed code they aren't actually getting the output they are expecting

Comment: second answer generates an error "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: 1st answer does work. Thank you to everyone that helped!