# Convert decimals to Hex

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert decimals into Hex:

```
string hex = IntToString(dezimal,
             new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                          'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'});
textBoxHexa.Text = hex;
```

But I get an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format

Is this even the best way to do it? If not, what better ways are there?

Comment: What's `IntToString`?

Comment: What is the implementation for IntToString?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690480/int-to-hex-string)

Comment: There is no need to convert.  Decimals are stored as numbers in binary.  You just need to change display method is you need a hex output.

Comment: you have to show the code thats failing. ie IntToString. Turn on 'break on exception thrown' in the Debug->Exception settings to see which line is failing

Comment: As the error message seems to bear no relation to the code shown - are you taking a user input string & then trying to parse that to an integer first. You would get "Input string was not in a correct format" exception if the user typed an invalid integer string (maybe a decimal) & you tried parsing with the Int32.Parse() method.

Answer (score -1):

Decimals can't be represented directly by hexadecimal, there's no floating point, for that you need a representation of the floating point number, the most common is the IEEE-754 representation which uses the actual processors.

In case you want that representation you can do this (using unsafe):

```
decimal m = 3.4353M;
byte* data = (byte*)&m;

string hex = "";

for(int buc = 0; buc < 16; buc++)
    hex += data[buc].ToString("X2");

//Result: 00000400000000003186000000000000
```

Comment: Look into `BitConverter.GetBytes()` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwsaf3w(v=vs.110).aspx).  It provides a managed way to get a byte representation of a value as a byte array, without the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Trevor Look at it by yourself, there's no conversion from decimal (decimal is not the same as float).

Comment: True, `GetBytes()` does not have an overload for .NET's `decimal` data type.  But NET's [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) data type is not an [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) defined type like you suggest.  The overload is likely missing because the internal representation of a framework-specific type would be of limited use.  To be honest, it's all moot until the OP provides more information.

Answer (score -3):

First of all `IntToString` converts an integer to string, not from decimal to hex.

Check [here](https://sm.alliedmods.net/new-api/string/IntToString) for `IntToString` use

TO convert from decimal to hex use the method: `ToString("X")`

```
// Store integer 50
int decValue = 50;

// Convert integer 182 as a hex in a string variable
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
```

Or you could use the following method as well:

```
string.format("{0:x}", decValue);
```

[Refer to this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)

Comment: You need to be more precise in your wording - you seem to imply that you can convert from "decimal" type to a hex string with _ToString("X")_. You will find this throws a FormatException. You can only use that formatting for integral types (short, int, long, ushort etc).

Comment: How do you know what IntToString does? We do not know the type of `dezimal` , it could be anyting

Comment: Stop posting random answers and test it by yourself. It fails miserably also.

Comment: for all we know dezimal is a string

Comment: @pm100 It cannot be string since the first argument for `IntToString` is an int argument.

Comment: @Ramesh how do you know what the first argument is?  OP has not provided the definition for that function. You’re literally guessing. This question is unanswerable until the OP provides a [MCVE]

Comment: @maccettura I am not guessing it but that is what is mentioned in the arguments of the function. Here is the definition of the `IntToString` function: `int IntToString(int num, char[] str, int maxlength)`

Comment: @Ramesh you’ve linked a random c++ library that includes an IntToString function. How on earth is that helpful or relevant?