# Decimal to Hex signed 2 Converter

Tags: c#, hex, converters

I want to translate a value to hex but the results are missing.

```
        int q = 0006038738;
        var w = q.ToString("X");
        //result: 5C24D2
        //I want that: 005C24D2
```

How do I incorporate the 0s at the beginning of the value I will convert?

Comment: Related to a X4 question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690480/int-to-hex-string/4690504. not exactly a dupe but a lot of question about X2 and X4 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var w = q.ToString("X8");
```

> The precision specifier indicates the minimum number of digits desired
>   in the resulting string. If required, the number is padded with zeros
>   to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision
>   specifier.

Reference: [The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier)